# mongoDB authentication error

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, driver, database

I'm new at mongoDB and am trying to connect using php driver..

this is my code :

```
$this->connection = new Mongo("mongodb://tatao_user:tatao_pass@ds043047.mongolab.com:43047/tatao");
```

but it didn't work and resulting in the error below :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Couldn't authenticate with database tatao: username [tatao_user]'

I've also tried using the shell, but the reuslt is the same.

please help....

Thx B4...

Comment: It may sound obvious but are you sure you are putting in the right username and pw? Have you tried pinging `ds043047.mongolab.com:43047` to see if it responds as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to check if mongodb is running and you have no errors.

Then if you are sure your credential (user and password) are right try this:

```
<?php

$mongo = new Mongo();

$db = $mongo->db_name; //replace db_name with your db name obviously

$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypassword";

$db->authenticate($username, $password);

?>
```

you should also check the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php

Then, i use **Codeigniter** too, and there is a really good **library for mongodb**, simple and fast, using **Active Records** and all the staffs as for the standard database library of CI.
I really suggest you to use that, you can check that here:

https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library

Comment: I've used the codeigniter library and still can't connect to it. the authenticate function is depricated and it gives error.

Comment: @Jason damn, i used that months ago maybe they changed somenthing, anyway the lib has a good mongodb.php config file you checked that right?